# Swapping the sharing page twitter logo by text

Tags: wordpress, post, twitter

I would like to add a share link from my wordpress website to tweeter.
I found how to do it but, I would like to remove the twitter logo and add a simple text link.
So I removed the twitter class "twitter-share-button" but I can't retrieve informations into the twitter textbox...

Here is my code:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" data-url="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" data-text="<?php the_title(); ?>" data-hashtags="hashtag" >THIS_TEXT_THAT_I_WANT_TO_DISPLAY and add all data content to the twitter text area</a>

<script>
!function(d,s,id){
var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){
js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}
(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
</script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build your own Twitter share URL. You don't need to include any javascript or the Twitter SDK, it's just an HTML link. More info on building your own at https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button, just scroll all the way to the bottom of the page. Try something like this for yourmarkup:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share?url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>&lang=en&text='<?php the_title(); ?>' via @yourtwitterhandle&conturl=<?php the_permalink(); ?>&count=vertical" target="_blank">Tweet this</a>
```

There are a lot of things you can pass into the url, so you can tweak this to get the result you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the result code:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share?url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>&lang=en&text='<?php the_title(); ?>'+via+@twitteraccount+:+Check+this+out+<?php the_permalink(); ?>&target="_blank">Tweet this</a>
```